# Handle "Connection reset by peer" error in haskell's wreq library

Tags: haskell, exception

I'm making multiple GET requests using Haskell's [`wreq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq) library. I want to handle connection errors retrying a limited number of times. I thought something like this would work:

```
getRetried url = retried 0
    where maxRetries = 2
          retried retries | retries >= maxRetries = throwError $ error "number of retries exceeded" 
                          | otherwise             = catchError (get url) (\_ -> (putStrLn "retrying") >> (retried (retries + 1) ) )
```

but it fails from time to time with the following error:

```
*** Exception: InternalIOException recv: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)
```

What am I missing? Isn't `catchError` the right way to handle errors?

Comment: Why `throwError . error`?

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment, `error` creates a "bottom value" which corresponds to an `Exception` which can only by caught by `Control.Exception.catch` and the like. You must use throwError by supplying the exception *directly*: `throwError $ ErrorCall "..."` (of course you should define your own exception type. The source of the exception is not `error` however, it is somewhere else (impossible to tell without full code) - you can still catch this with something like `ErrorT (try $ ...)`.